# Cannot log in to the MySQL server (PhpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

**I installed both MySQL and PhpMyAdmin via Homebrew.** I get the following error when I try to login with root and its password:

```
Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I can log in to MySQL via the terminal with:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**PhpMyAdmin config:**

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'pass';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

I'm running this on **apache**. I tried all the solutions on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried to post localhost instead of the loopback ip as host?

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, no difference

Comment: @LelioFaieta I decided to double check and now it works, thanks!

Comment: Glad to know! Please mark as solved my answer then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as host declaration.

In your case you can try to use `localhost` and it will work.

Comment: To clarify a bit, both are valid host declarations but they are handled differently by MySQL. `localhost` is a socket connection; `127.0.0.1` is TCP/IP networking. If the port is blocked or if MySQL is not listening for TCP/IP connections, then `localhost` must be used. Additionally, the permissions are different within MySQL -- the wildcard host indicator `%` does not match `localhost` connections.

Answer (score 5):

The error "`Cannot Log in to MySQL server`" can have multiple causes.
It simply means, that phpMyAdmin is not able to connect to the MySQL Server in general.

I had this issue too - in my case I've freshly installed MySQL. During the installation process a new root password is generated. But the MySQL Server forces you to set a new password for the root user, before that you can't execute any query. Sadly phpMyAdmin does not reflect the exact cause properly and just reports a failed connection `'Cannot log in to the MySQL server'`.

I fixed it by

1. logging into my mysql server with my cli:

   `mysql -u root -p`
2. update root password:

   `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE');`

Comment: Thanks for that! I have used mysql Workbench to reset the password. The issue was the password has expired but phpMyAdmin gives no message about it.