# Cannot log in to my phpMyAdmin when changed password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I just set a database with XAMPP and it works fine, except when I try to change the password. I have tried changing it with this command:  mysqladmin --user=root --password="" password "123"

Now the passsword should be 123 for the root user. Now when I try to enter the web server hosting the client to use with the database, I get an error:
MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.

This seems fine with me, I haven't specified any password. Then I open the my.ini file and change the password to 123 and remove the hashtag so it looks like this: password       = 123

But I still can't log in.

I have looked at these suggestions but they don't work for me:
[how to get login option for phpmyadmin in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759776/how-to-get-login-option-for-phpmyadmin-in-xampp)

[Cannot log in to the MySQL server (PhpMyAdmin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870637/cannot-log-in-to-the-mysql-server-phpmyadmin)

Comment: When storing passwords in mysql, I think instead of `password = 123` you need to run `password = password(123)`. It's how mysql cryptographs it's passwords.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The phpMyAdmin configuration file is `config.inc.php`, not `my.ini`. Normally the "invalid settings" message comes because of some syntax problem with your configuration; can you include your `config.inc.php` here (obscuring any sensitive information)? You might also try loading it directly, as in https://localhost/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php to see if that reports any PHP syntax errors.